# is it possible to load unique item or one of a kind item from sql using php? (check image)

Tags: php, sql

[image: My database]

The image above is my sql database. what I want to do is load the names and echo in json but the thing is though, I want to show one of each name. Like see how there are 4 assassinshadow entries? I want php to echo only one of em. not making much sense am I? haha

Comment: "I want php to echo only one of em. not making much sense am I? haha" if you are aware that your question doesn't make much sense, then perhaps clarify it instead of posting it?

Comment: Well without any code it's pretty hard to retrieve anything from a database and show it... What have you tried and what does or doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do that:

```
SELECT distinct name FROM my_table
```

or

```
SELECT name FROM my_table group by name
```

Comment: Why group by when no aggregate functions are involved? I mean, distinct is just fine! (You can also do SELECT name FROM my_table union SELECT name FROM my_table to get distinct values!)

Comment: the second option is what I needed Thank you !!! :)

Comment: @jarlh, I agree that in this case DISTINCT looks cleaner, but according to [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/distinct-optimization.html) these two clauses are equivalent from optimization perspective.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DISTINCT in your mysql query:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$query  = "SELECT DISTINCT name from yourtable";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
```